# How to decode Json text with encoded Unicode characters in Apache Flink streaming application output

Tags: json, scala, decode, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm working with Flink and am writing a Scala program where I set up a connection to the Twitter streaming API using Flink's Twitter Connector and fetch / process tweets based on a rule and finally:

1. Display them in stdout (I'm using IntelliJ Idea for development).
2. Save them to a txt file.

Tweets containing text with greek or other special characters appears both in stdout and the txt file as for example:

```
"text":"test \u03c6\u03bb\u03af\u03bd\u03ba"
```

How can I render correctly the escaped JSON text? (I'm using a Windows server machine for development if that plays a role too).

The relevant code is as follows:

```
val source = new TwitterSource(props)
source.setCustomEndpointInitializer(myCustomEndpoint)
val streamSource = env.addSource(source)

streamSource.print()
streamSource.writeAsText("file:\\\\C:\\test.txt", org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
```

Comment: That's raw ASCII representation of unicode escapes for the characters "φλίνκ", where do you see any UTF-16 here at all? At least in this particular example, there are no surrogate pairs. Would [this here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) solve your problem?

Comment: That text looks like JSON text with encoded Unicode characters (note that it's not UTF-16, that's a binary encoding for Unicode characters, what you have are escaped Unicode characters). So it's not a Flink issue, right? You just need to decode the text before emitting it.

Comment: @kkrugler indeed, you are correct it's JSON text (I'm not familiar at all with character encoding). How would I work to decode it before writing it to a txt file?

Comment: Normally when you parse the JSON, you get back Java strings which will be unescaped. If you have to explicitly unescape the strings yourself, then (as @Andrey Tyukin noted) you can use the StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson() method to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I use the StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson() as follows in the streamSource.print() method: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(streamSource.print().toString()) but still get the escaped Json strings like in that extract: {"created_at":"Sun Jun 02 10:06:53 +0000 2019","id":1135125625365303296,"id_str":"1135125625365303296","text":"\ud83d\udcfb\ud83c\udfa7\u039c\u03b7\u03bd \u03c7\u03ac\u03c3\u03b5\u03c4\u03b5 ...

Should I use it in a different way? Probably I'm doing this wrong.